# NoMethodError in Rails for method defined in Helpers/Controller/Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nomethoderror

(Preface: I am 10 months into learning Rails so this could be a really rookie mistake.)

My app has `Venues` which have `VenueCategories` associated with them. In my `Venue` view, I want to populate some hash tags into the share content when a user shares the `Venue` to Twitter. For this, I have created a method (albeit perhaps not an ideal implementation, will look to refactor later) `hash_tags` to be called on the VenueCategory. First I put this in **VenueCategoriesHelper.rb** and got NoMethodError when calling it in the console to test. I moved the method to both the Model and the Controller just to test it out but yielded the same results.

I have tried defining the method with and without passing the `venue_category` as a parameter.

What am I doing wrong? Relevant code below.

**VenueCategoriesHelper.rb**

```
def hash_tags(venue_category)
  hash_tags = []
  hash_tag_string = ""
  if venue_category.name == "Restaurant"
    hash_tags << "#restaurants"
  elsif venue_category.name == "Salons & Spas"
    hash_tags << ["#salons", "#spas"]
  elsif venue_category.name == "Hotels & Resorts"
    hash_tags << ["#hotels", "#resorts"]
  elsif venue_category.name == "Bars & Nightlife"
    hash_tags << ["#bars", "#nightlife"]
  end
  hash_tags.each do |h|
    hash_tag_string << "#{h} "
  end
end
```

**show.html.slim (random snippet added to view to test**

```
...
p = resource.venue_category.hash_tags(resource.venue_category)

#header-module
  #overall-score-container
    #overall-score-header
...
```

**Error from Console and when running in browser**

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `hash_tags' for #<VenueCategory:0x007ff2134b69c0>
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: so you are defining the method and in the first line of the method you redefine the method to be an array? try renaming that variable. but that should no tbe yu problem for now. you try to access the method on a model instance, so it should be within the model. after that do a `reload!` in the console.

Comment: Wrote the last comment after your update. Let me try this as well.

Comment: Code is now in the Model, but NoMethodError persists.

Comment: You do a `VenueCategory.new.hash_tags(:foo)`? If so, does the error persist, when you exit the console and restart it?

Comment: Yes, method persists after restarting console and trying that command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helper modules are included in the scope of the view renderer, not the model.  Change the view code to:

```
p = hash_tags(resource.venue_category)
```

Comment: .. while the method is in the helper.

Comment: Nailed it. The method implementation apparently really sucks, but I can clean that up. Error is resolved - thank you!!